# Send msg betwen js and python in QtWebKit

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtwebkit, pyside

I found this topic in wiki:
https://wiki.qt.io/Using-QtWebKit-and-QML-with-PySide. 
But I cannot run the sample program from it.
I use pyqt4 and get the following error

```
$ ./main1.py 
Traceback (most recent call last): File “./main1.py”, line 35, in <module> view.setSource(file.replace(’.py’, ‘.qml’))
TypeError: QDeclarativeView.setSource(QUrl): argument 1 has unexpected type ‘str’
```

Anybody have souces code from this toturial? 
Maybe my problem is that I use pyqt4 instead of pyside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have enough information in the exception.

```
TypeError: QDeclarativeView.setSource(QUrl): argument 1 has unexpected type ‘str’
```

Here, `QDeclarativeView.setSource(QUrl)` says `setSource` method for `QDeclarativeView` expects a `QUrl` argument and instead you given a plain string.

Try this:

```
view.setSource(QtCore.QUrl(file.replace(’.py’, ‘.qml’)))
```

Of course, you also need to import `QtCore`.

Regarding whether this is different in `PyQt4` vs `PySide`: I doubt that. `PySide` documentation for [`QDeclarativeView.setSource`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/PySide/QtDeclarative/QDeclarativeView.html#PySide.QtDeclarative.PySide.QtDeclarative.QDeclarativeView.setSource) also states a `QUrl` argument. But `PySide` may change strings to `QUrl` under the hood. That I am not sure.